# I cant install PyGMO in mac

Tags: python, pip

i'm trying to install PyGMO to play around with it in mac OS and it's impossible. I used "brew install pygmo" but the python code is not running.

I'm trying to use Python3, i don't know if i am doing it right. I also can't locate it in pip3.

Everything you guys know will be perfect for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting.

Comment: Also, you can try using conda instead
`conda install -c conda-forge pygmo`